# Bracket notation elements["name"] randomly turns out undefined where elements.namedItem("name") works

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, element, square-bracket

**Question Outline**

I have an HTML page with JavaScript code within, generated via PHP. Normally, the `elements["name"]` bracket notation works properly, and I can access the named element this way. However, after several maneuvers through the pages, the same page will act up, and random `elements["name"]` calls will turn up as `undefined`... Checking the HTML source and DOM Explorer, the corresponding HTML elements are still there, so it seems the JavaScript side is somehow unable to access the elements... And even stranger, an `elements.namedItem("name")` call to the same elements in the same condition *works* for some reason...

These two calls should be equivalent, according to this MDN reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection#Usage_in_JavaScript

I am unable to find either a clear reproducible pattern, or a good reason behind this behavior, and so am thinking that I use the latter call to be safe, but am grateful for any documentary reasoning behind this failure... if any such exist.

---

**Environment**

Internet Explorer 11 running in IE modes 5 to 8 runs into this problem; strangely, the same Internet Explorer 11 running in IE modes 9, 10, or Edge do not show this problem for some reason or another...

---

**Codes**

*JavaScript snippet*

```
formel=document.forms.MyTestForm.elements;
el=document.getElementById("errorlogarea");

//formel.type[27] won't work because of the square brackets...

//formel["type[27]"] turns out to be undefined...?
if(formel["type[27]"]!=undefined) el.innerHTML+="t27-1:"+formel["type[27]"].value+"<br>";

//...but formel.namedItem("type[27]") correctly gets the (hidden) input...???
if(formel.namedItem("type[27]")!=undefined) el.innerHTML+="t27-2:"+formel.namedItem("type[27]").value+"<br>";
```

*HTML snippet*

```
<form id="MyTestForm" action="(this-page)" method="POST" onSubmit="return CheckBeforeSubmit();">
...
<div class="errorlog" id="errorlogarea"></div><br>
...
<input type="hidden" name="type[27]" value="any">
...
</form>
```

Comment: About the `I am unable to find either a clear reproducible pattern`, you write that IE 11 in 5 to 8 mode has that problem, but never (?) in the 9 to 11 mode.  Does the behavior in IE in the 5 to 8 mode change when reloading, or just for other elements?

Comment: Have you declared a `!DOCTYPE` ? IE<=8 requires a doctype to be defined, in order to target attribute-selectors.

Comment: @t.niese : Once the behavior happens, the elements which act up are constant, even after reloading the page (even in different IE modes). Upon restarting IE itself, the problems seems fixed for a while, and then reappears, sometimes with the same elements, sometimes different... which is all the more puzzling...

Comment: @Eric : on the pages there is a combined `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN'>` and also a `<meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=EmulateIE9'>`, which in combination makes IE work in IE5 mode by default.